# How to get a corresponding MonoDevelop.Projects.Dom.IType from System.Type?

Tags: types, mono, assemblies, add-in, monodevelop

I'm trying to do what is descriped in question's title.
To do it i've found only one way but id gives me no expected results.

I do the following:

```
System.Type type = ...; //known System.Type instance;
var dom = ProjectDomService.GetAssemblyDom(project.TargetRuntime, type.Assembly.FullName);
```

After that (as i expect) `dom.Types` should contain all assembly exported typed but it's empty;

Is there any way to get IType from Type?

UPD: (solved)

Here the cod that helps to obtain a correct AssemblyDom instance and then Get IType by name:

```
string assemblyName = targetRuntime.AssemblyContext
                        .GetAssemblyNameForVersion(type.Assembly.FullName, targetFramework);

var assemblyLocation = targetRuntime.AssemblyContext
            .GetAssemblyLocation(assemblyName, targetFramework);

var assemblyDom = ProjectDomService.GetAssemblyDom(targetRuntime, assemblyLocation);

var t = assemblyDom.GetType(type.FullName);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Despite the parameter name, I *think* GetAssemblyDom's second parameter is the assembly file path, not the assembly name. (Even if it can resolve assembly names, that would only be true for system assemblies or packages in the target runtime.)

The reason there is no simple lookup from a System.Type to an IType is that it is almost never needed. The purpose of IType is to avoid loading assemblies and real types, since they can't be unloaded, and it's not possible to load Types from different frameworks or assemblies. Therefore, code that deals with general ITypes should never deal with general Types.

IType is also much more memory efficient - the ProjectDom assembly databases have indices that help make code completion fast, and allow information can be lazily loaded and then unloaded in  granular way.

Comment: Hi Michael! TY, your answer seems to be correct, because i've solved my problem with code that correlate with what you just said (code example is in question's update). My task was to obtain all classes in my solution that inherits a Type from known assembly. I understand what IType with - if there is no assembly yet (only a code) so we can't do any reflection through it.

Comment: IMHO, there is a disadvantage in AssemblyDom creation factory (mb this is a festure). If i pass a wrong 2nd parameter to ProjectDomService.GetAssemblyDom, it's silently created with an empty Dom so the object is useless and its't not understood where exactly a trouble if any or what kind of a trouble it is.

Comment: That sounds like a bug, IMO it should throw an exception or return null.

Comment: I think the same. It's more expectable behavior.